# Junit tests fail in TravisCi/CircleCi

Tags: java, spring, junit, gradle

I'm developing an application using Spring. The application has some Junit tests.

In my computer (local), all the tests are successfull. But when I upload the application to TravisCi or CircleCi, all the test fails with the message:

> FAILED
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException
>           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
>                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/release" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'empresalia'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/release" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

mainClassName = "universando.Application"

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT")
    compile("org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:0.17.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:1.2.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.1.6.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.6.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.6.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.6.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-tx:4.1.6.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.7.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.2.7.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.7.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:4.0.1.RELEASE")
    compile("javax.mail:mail:1.4.7")
    compile("javax.activation:activation:1.1")
    compile("org.apache.velocity:velocity:1.7")
    compile("org.apache.velocity:velocity-tools:2.0")
    compile("com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.9.1")
    compile("com.maxmind.geoip:geoip-api:1.2.10")
    compile("com.cybozu.labs:langdetect:1.1-20120112")
    compile("org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.6")   

    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:1.2.3.RELEASE")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.2.3.RELEASE")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '1.10' }
```

Any ideas to solve it? Thanks

Comment: I think you're going to have to post more context about the logs. I deleted my earlier response because it does sound like a server configuration issue after all.

Comment: Do you have any stacktrace or already identified which class failed to load on Travis?